# Bound on the solution of a constrained least squares problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a full row rank matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. I want to show that there exists $K>0$ depending only on $m, n, A, b$ such that, for any vector $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}$, the optimization problem
$$
\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2,\\
\text{s.t.}\ \ -\alpha\le x \le \alpha
$$
has a solution $x^*$ such that $\|x^*\|\le K$.

By $-\alpha\le x \le \alpha$, I mean that for any $i=1,\cdots,n$, we have $-\alpha_i\le x_i \le \alpha_i$. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Does $x\leqslant α$ mean $x\preccurlyeq α$?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco, it means coordinatewise inequality. I have just added an explanation.

Comment: clearly, $\| x^{*} \| \leq \sqrt{N\alpha^{2}}$.  That bound is valid for any $x$ that satisfies the bound constraints.

Comment: @BrianBorchers We are interested in a bound independent of $\alpha$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, You are somehow right, however we should note that here we some constraints.

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi You are correct. One could use linear programming to determine whether the intersection of the solution set of $A x = b$ and the box defined by $|x_i| \leq \alpha_i$ is empty or not. If empty, use least-squares. If non-empty, use least-norm.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum norm least squares solution to $\min \| Ax -b \|_{2}^{2}$ is given by the pseudoinverse solution

$x^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}b$

For values of $\alpha$ greater than or equal to $L=\| x^{\dagger} \|_{\infty}$, $x^{\dagger}$ will be inside the box and will be an optimal solution.

For values of $\alpha$ less than $L$, the box is contained within a Euclidean ball of radius $K=\sqrt{nL^2}$.

Either way, an optimal solution to the box-constrained problem lies within a Euclidean ball of radius $K=\sqrt{nL^{2}}$.

Furthermore, this is the best possible bound since for large values of $\alpha$ there will be no optimal solution with a smaller norm than $x^{\dagger}$.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that $\alpha$ is a scalar.  However, the bound that I've given is valid for all vectors $\alpha$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, thanks for the answer. However, the claim "For values of $\alpha$ less than $L$, the box is contained within a Euclidean ball of radius $K=\sqrt{nL^2}$." only holds if $\alpha$ is a vector with equal entries. Note that $\alpha$ is a vector with possible different entries. I am interested in reason of your claim that the bound is valid in general.

Comment: Pardon my overly quick response- I had only a few minutes between classes.  I agree that this won't work for arbitrary vectors $\alpha$, and I don't think you'll be able to get any useful bound indpendent of $\alpha$.